# How to open kendo window on click

Tags: kendo-ui

please go through the code below. In below grid, I've a column with hyperlink. I want to open a kendo window when i click on the particular link. How can i achieve this. Currently it is navigating to some other page.

```
@model IEnumerable<WeBOC.Support.Entities.ImportUnit>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Import Units";
}

<h2>Import Units</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitNbr).Width(150).ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("#=UnitNbr#", "UnitInspector", new { id = "#=UnitId#" }).ToHtmlString()).Title("Unit No.");
        columns.Bound(p => p.VIRNbr).Width(150).Title("VIR No.");
        columns.Bound(p => p.BLNbr).Width(150).Title("BL No.");
        columns.Bound(p => p.IGMStatus).Width(80).Title("IGM Status");
        columns.Bound(p => p.LineCode).Width(80).Title("Line Code");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Arrived).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}").Width(150).Title("Arrived"); 
    })    
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()    
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to create hyperlinks, how to invoke javascript functions and how to pass parameters is all covered in [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change your client template to a simple html-element such as an a-element and assing a javascript function to this element which opens your window?

```
...
columns.Bound(p => p.UnitNbr).Width(150).ClientTemplate("<a id="myId>Unit No.</a>);
...
```

and then use jquery:

```
$("#myId").click(function() {
    $("#kendoWindow").data("kendoWindow").open();
});
```

Comment: Above code is not working. Infact, i think the function is not being called at all. I've also test this by using alert in that function, but no response. Second, may i have to define a kendo window on same page?

Comment: I forgot some " in my code, the template should be "<a id=\"myId\">Unit No.</a>"

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your template so the links have a css class:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.UnitNbr).Width(150).ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("#=UnitNbr#", "UnitInspector", new { id = "#=UnitId#" }, new { @class="someclass" }).ToHtmlString()).Title("Unit No.");
```

Then use jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".someclass", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var address = $(this).attr("href");
    $("<div/>").kendoWindow({ 
        content: address 
    }).data("kendoWindow").open();
});
```